# "Forbidden" error when uploading file through Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using the "google-api-services-storage-v1beta2-rev5-java-1.15.0-rc.zip" Google Cloud Storage library together with the "StorageSample.java" sample program from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java?repo=samples)

I have followed the sample program's setup instructions and have set up the "client_secrets.json" and "sample_settings.json" files. The sample program compiles OK but runs only partially OK.

I have modified the "uploadObject" method of the "StorageSample.java" program so that it uploads a test file created by me (rather than upload a randomly generated file). The program runs OK in the following methods :

```
tryCreateBucket();
getBucket();
listObjects();
getObjectMetadata();
```

However, when running the "uploadObject(true)" method, I get the following error

```
================== Uploading object. ==================

Forbidden
```

My modified "uploadObject" method is listed below :

```
private static void uploadObject(boolean useCustomMetadata) throws IOException {
  View.header1("Uploading object.");
  File file = new File("My_test_upload_file.txt");
  if (!file.exists() || !file.isFile()) {
      System.out.println("File does not exist");
      System.exit(1);
  }
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  long byteCount = file.length();
  InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", inputStream);
  mediaContent.setLength(byteCount);
  StorageObject objectMetadata = null;
  if (useCustomMetadata) {
      List<ObjectAccessControl> acl = Lists.newArrayList();  // empty acl (seems default acl).
      objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
             .setName("myobject")
             .setMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"))
             .setAcl(acl)
             .setContentDisposition("attachment");        
  }
  Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert("mybucket", objectMetadata, mediaContent);
  if (!useCustomMetadata) {
    insertObject.setName("myobject");
  }
  if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= 2 * 1000 * 1000 /* 2MB */) {
    insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
  }
  insertObject.execute();
}
```

In the 1st run of the program, a bucket is created and I get the "Forbidden" error when uploading my created test file. In subsequent runs, the "Forbidden" errors persist.

I think that as the bucket is created by the program, the program should have enough access right to upload a file to that bucket.

Is there any setup / operation that I have missed ? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, what a careless mistake. I have forgotten to change the "mybucket" name to my created bucket's name.

The program now runs OK.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but it doesn't work for large file, but reading in the given example provided by Google, It seems to work with large file (100MB as it's commented). Do you know how to do that? Thank you so much